# laravel: duplicate record on using saveMany in many to many morph

Tags: php, laravel

I developed this code to save new tags and associate them to post model

```
    $tags_obj = [];

    foreach($tags as $tag){

        $new_tag = \App\Tag::firstOrNew(['name' => $tag]);
        array_push($tags_obj, $new_tag);
    }

   $saved_tags =  $post->tags()->saveMany($tags_obj);

    $tags_id = array_map(function($tag){
             return $tag->id;
      },$saved_tags);

    $post->tags()->sync($tags_id);
```

new tags will be saved in `tags` table but  duplicated data is saved in `taggable` table , it means `saveMany` method  touch both `tags` and `taggable` tables , and its unable to check duplicate record existence in `taggable` table.is there any approach to prevent `saveMany` from touching `taggable` table?